how is a complex number converted to a form that can be played with pyaudio or sound device?
I have created some audio that I would like to play through a speaker using Ifft in python. It gives an array of complex numbers and as such no good to use with pyaudio or sound device.
I tried to get the magnitude if the complex number and use that but the fft data is not correct if i do that. Thank you in advance
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample rate
sr = 500
# time interval
ts = 1/sr
# create bins, 1 second worth
t = np.arange(0,1,ts,dtype=complex)

# fill the array with all 0 + 0i
o=0
for i in t:
    t[o] = 0+0j
    o += 1

# fill bins
t[20] = 10+20j
t[4] = 4+2j
t[100] = 6 + 6j

# do ifft to get into time domain
txout = np.fft.ifft(t)

# combine real and imaginary to get samples for pyaudio
txf = np.arange(0,1,ts,dtype=complex)
u = 0
for i in txout:
    txf[u] = np.sqrt(pow(txout.real[u],2) + pow(txout.imag[u],2))
    u += 1

# play sound through speakers here 

# is the receiver, works as txout, txf does not have correct frequency nor complex number
rx = np.fft.fft(txf)

#print complex number for all bins form fft
q=0
for f in rx:
    print("bin: ", q, " Val: ", rx[q])
    q += 1

# plot the results, fft and time domain
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.plot(txf)
ax2.plot(rx)
plt.show()


Well, the output of an FFT (or IFFT) is in general a complex vector. So, it has twice as much information as a real-valued signal (like audio samples) of the same length. Thus, you need to define what information you care about and reduce it to that. We can't tell you what that is, because we don't know why you would want to "play" the discrete Fourier transform as audio (it makes no sense, at least to me).

also, your python code looks like it was written by someone who only knew ANSI C (and that not too well) before they touched python; that's not a criticism of you, but things like your Re² + Im² of a numpy vector are just txf = txout.real**2 + txout.imag**2, no need for pow, nor the very slow element-wise loop! (also, you definitely haven't understood how python for loops work).

"fft data is not correct if i do that." You will have to explain that. The data is exactly what you instruct your computer to compute. What would make it correct, by your defintion of "correct"? We can't know that…

@Marcus Müller I am working to a ODFM implantation using QAM mainly to help with understanding of the concepts. I have a degree in cs where I used c mainly. As for the data not being correct, if I take the fft of txout the fft shows the signals in the correct bin. On the other hand if I take the fft of txf the signals are not in the correct bins. Thank you, Sam

But OFDM assumes you're doing complex baseband. And that's not what audio is. You need a quadrature mixer to convert your thus-gained complex baseband to a carrier frequency, so that is has no negative frequency components anymore,

For real signals the spectrum has Hermitian symmetry, i.e. you need to make sure that complex values at positive and negative frequencies are complex conjugate of each other and that the values at DC and Nyquist are real.
The easiest way to ensure the symmetry is to only work with the positive frequencies and use fft.rifft() for the inverse transform.
# create the positive half of the spectrum
t = np.zeros(sr // 2 + 1, dtype=complex)

# fill bins
t[20] = 10+20j
t[4] = 4+2j
t[100] = 6 + 6j

# do a real ifft to get into time domain
txout = np.fft.irfft(t)


In many audio applications, operations carried out in the transformed domain are (or should be) of such a nature that the signal post ifft either is purely real, or nearly real. In the latter case you can just ditch the imaginary part.
